# Picasso disk caching

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images from a URL

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(product.getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
```

From what I can see this is going to the url everytime and not caching to disk. I need disk caching enabled

I have permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So its not a issue with disk. I think the issue is that the server is not sending back a cache param so HTTP Client is not caching.

How can I force Picasso use the disk cache at all times?

Answer (score 3):

Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. The library relies on HTTP clients to honor the semantics of the very well-defined caching headers for keeping things locally on disk.

Because of this fact, there is no way to force caching.

Comment: Does this means that Picasso always needs connection even to use a cached image?

Comment: No. The HTTP client will serve from the cache if offline.

Comment: I have tested with "airplane mode" activated, it does not work for me. Should work as well?