# Picasso can't load cached image when no network

Tags: picasso

Picasso can perfectly load image in condition of having network,but once turned off network and quited app,start app from launcher,there is no image showing.
please help me~

My code as follows:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.imageloading).into(imageView);
```

Comment: [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635506/picasso-disk-caching),but how to open HTTP Client cache?

Comment: I had same issue. Downgraded Picasso to version 2.4

Answer (score 2):

Picasso caches images at first time  but when your disk cache is out of memory it starts to free up some spaces.
check this for more information
https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-influencing-image-caching